# Force python to ignore pyc files when dynamically loading modules from filepaths

Tags: python

I need to import python modules by filepath (e.g., "/some/path/to/module.py") known only at runtime and ignore any `.pyc` files should they exist.

This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3503970/226037) suggests the use of `imp.load_module` as a solution but this approach also appears to use a `.pyc` version if it exists.

**importme.py**

```
SOME_SETTING = 4
```

**main.py:**

```
import imp
if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = 'importme'
    openfile, pathname, description = imp.find_module(name)
    module = imp.load_module(name, openfile, pathname, description)
    openfile.close()
    print module
```

Executing twice, the `.pyc` file is used after first invocation:

```
$ python main.py 
<module 'importme' from '/Users/dbryant/temp/pyc/importme.py'>

$ python main.py 
<module 'importme' from '/Users/dbryant/temp/pyc/importme.pyc'>
```

Unfortunately, `imp.load_source` has the same behavior (from the docs):

> Note that if a properly matching byte-compiled file (with suffix .pyc
>   or .pyo) exists, it will be used instead of parsing the given source
>   file.

Making *every* script-containing directory read-only is the only solution that I know of (prevents generation of `.pyc` files in the first place) but I would rather avoid it if possible.

(note: using python 2.7)

Comment: Why do you want to prevent use of pyc files? It will only use the pyc file if it's the same as the py. If you change the py, it will recompile the pyc.

Comment: @Falmarri It's complicated.  It has to do with the fact that different types of machines are accessing the same set of python files and they seem to produce incompatible byte-compilations of the same source code (such that the pyc generated by machine A is not readable by machine B, causing machine B to fail to import the module dynamically); and yes, all machines are using the interpreter binary.

Comment: The only reason different machines would write different bytecode is if they're running different versions of the interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

`load_source` does the right thing for me, i.e.

```
dir, name = os.path.split(path)
mod = imp.load_source(name, path)
```

uses the .py variant even if a pyc file is available - name ends in `.py` under python3. The obvious solution is obviously to delete all .pyc files before loading the file - the race condition may be a problem though if you run more than one instance of your program.

One other possibility: Iirc you can let python interpret files from memory - i.e. load the file with the normal file API and then compile the in-memory variant. Something like:

```
path = "some Filepath.py"
with open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    data = file.read()
exec(compile(data, "<string>", "exec")) # fair use of exec, that's a first!
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't even consider exec'ing the settings file/module contents.   This would also be a workable solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

How about using zip files containing python sources instead:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert("package.zip")
```

Comment: Interesting, but doesn't really work well for my use-case.  The modules that I'm dynamically loading are settings files and need to be easily human-readable and editable.

Comment: You could also look at using PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE environment variable.

Comment: Good point.  That would also work, but the only pyc files that are causing issues are those that are dynamically loaded with `imp` and I would like to be able to still use byte-code versions for everything else when available.

Comment: Could set that environment variable using sys.dont_write_bytecode, imp your modules and then change the bytecode setting back to the way it was to achieve this?

Comment: @Sanjamal Thanks, if your suggestion works then yes it would be sufficient for me.  I will test it.

Comment: @Sanjamal Your solution works perfectly.  If you submit it as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You could mark the directories containing the .py files as read-only.

Comment: Yes, I know (see bottom of question) but this isn't really solving the problem and is very inconvenient because I do need to still write to the containing directories for logs, outputs, etc.

Comment: I don't know what you're exact situation is, but I usually try to avoid writing data to the same directory that contains code.

Comment: I agree in principle, but python settings files blur the line between data and code in this case (very common practice in Django for example)